# Receiving email with .csv attachment with google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

I have been able to read emails, and I can see the attachments, but they don't come in as .csv data. I guess it is an 'EncodedPayload' type?

The following code:

```
for filename, content in attachments:
    logging.info("filename: " + filename)
    fileReader = csv.reader(content.split("\n"))
```

gave me this error:

```
'EncodedPayload' object has no attribute 'split'
```

How do I parse a csv file given an EncodedPayload ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call `decode()` on your content:

```
fileReader = csv.reader(content.decode())
```

Comment: Thanks! I received a warning saying 'this request used a high amount of CPU...' Is there any way to process large csv files slowly, or is this just something I'll have to deal with?

Comment: that is probably answered elsewhere on this site or warrants it's own question... but I'll give you a hint: The Task Queue is your friend ;-)